# Check if current user has permissions to create work items

Tags: api, tfs, azure-devops

Is there an endpoint in TFS rest api that i can use to check if the current logged in user has enough permissions to create a new TFS work item ?

Comment: Hi @Ridene Mohamed Aziz. Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if Shamrai Aleksander's answer could solve this issue. If yes, you may consider accepting it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to use validation with the `validateOnly` parameter [Work Items - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1).
PowerShell sample:

```
$pat = '<pat>'
$url = 'https://dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>/_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?validateOnly=true&api-version=6.1-preview.3'


$body = '[{"op":"add","path":"/fields/System.Title","from":null,"value":"Sample task"}]'


$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "",$pat)))

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Body $body
```

Result:

[image]

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF237111: The current user does not have permissions to save work items under the specified area path.","typeName":"Microsoft.Azure.Boards.WebApi.Com
mon.PermissionDeniedException, Microsoft.Azure.Boards.WebApi.Common","typeKey":"PermissionDeniedException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
At line:10 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -ContentType "application/js ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```